# java.sql.sqlexception invalid column index

Tags: java, sql, oracle, servlets

Hello everyone can someone tell me what is wrong here ?
I have a task i was asked and i am new in connecting oracle databases with java servlet.

here is me code:

```
try {
    out.print("first");
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    out.print("aaa");
    Connection con
            = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "myusername", "mypassword");
    out.print("111");
    PreparedStatement ps = con
            .prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO signup 
         values(fn, ln, date, em, pa, crnum)
    ");
                    out.print("222");
    ps.setString(1, fn);
    ps.setString(2, ln);
    ps.setString(3, da);
    ps.setString(4, em);
    ps.setString(5, pa);
    ps.setString(6, cr);

    int i = ps.executeUpdate();
    if (i > 0) {
        out.print("You are successfully registered...");
    }

} catch (Exception e2) {
    out.println(e2);
}

out.close();
response.sendRedirect("address");
/* when press next bottom 
        it'll take me to add.html*/
```

and after i ran the whole code i get this :`java.sql.sqlexception: invalid column index`

Comment: What line does the stacktrace refer to?

Comment: *"INSERT INTO signup values(fn,ln,date,em,pa,crnum)"* ... instressting style in writing a prepared statement. And I guess there is no tutorial out there to tell you how it really works, right?

Answer (score 4):

In your SQL statement, you have to provide the tokens or placeholders for your bind variable like in the following...

```
 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO signup values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
 ps.setString(1,fn);
 ps.setString(2,ln);
 ps.setString(3,da);
 ps.setString(4,em);
 ps.setString(5,pa);
 ps.setString(6,cr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use placeholder `?`:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO signup values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```